# LookML error - "Model Not Found" when viewing the Looker dashboard outside development mode

Tags: looker

I am able to create a visualization in Looker dashboard using explore in development mode. However, once I exit the development mode, I get the error LookML error - "Model Not Found".

I referred https://www.certification-questions.com/pdf-download/google/lookml-developer-pdf.pdf whose Q6 says that "The developer has not added users to the new model set" is the reason behind this error.

I created a new model set from https://cloud.looker.com/admin/roles and I have the Developer permission. The Developer role has Developer permission for all model sets.

I am unable to figure out which permission should be provided in order to view the dashboard outside the development mode.

[LookML error outside development mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxedm.png)
`{ "data": { "error": "Model Not Found" }, "dashboard_element_id": "4", "id": "29b7dab0e7244c7800c62dfa01e33b8e", "status": "error" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the created visualization outside the development mode, you will have to push, commit, and deploy your code. Then only it would be accessible outside the development mode.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are using Git platforms (Github or Gitlab), it's either you using local git repo or there could be a synchronization problem between your master and production branches.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).